# xorg touchscreen: how to do not keep mouse over the latest click

Tags: gtk, touchscreen, xorg

I have a touchscreen with linux embedded, xorg and gtk3.
My problem is that after a click the mouse pointer stucks over
the clicked button making his color different from other buttons.
What I would need is that the mouse pointer would go away after the click.
It seems that in order to have this result I need to work directly in xorg
(and not from gtk).
I paste my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier      "Single head configuration"
    InputDevice     "touchscreen" "CorePointer"
    Screen      0   "Screen0" Absolute 0 0
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option          "BlankTime" "0"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier      "Generic Keyboard"
    Driver          "evdev"
    Option          "XkbLayout"     "it"
    Option          "Device"        "/dev/input/event2"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "touchscreen"
#    Driver "evdev"
    Driver "tslib"

    Option "Calibration" "200 3850 300 3850"
    Option "Debug"
    Option "SwapAxes" "True"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
#    Option "MinX" "0"
#    Option "MaxX" "800"
#    Option "MinY" "0"
#    Option "MaxY" "480"
#    Option "MinX" "200"
#    Option "MaxX" "3850"
#    Option "MinY" "300"
#    Option "MaxY" "3850"
    Option "MoveLimit" "10"
    Option "DeviceName" "touchscreen"
#   Option "ReportingMode" "Raw"
    Option "Protocol" "Auto"
    Option "longtouched_action" "down"
    Option "longtouched_button" "1"
#    Option "Emulate3Buttons"
#    Option "Emulate3Timeout" "50"
    Option "SendCoreEvents" "On"
EndSection
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a GTK+ theme suitable for touchscreens, one that doesn't prelight buttons when the mouse is over them.  I don't know if such themes exist.